# Specifying path of imread in openCV

Tags: opencv

using openCV 2.4.8

I want to use imread and specify the path to the picture. I stuck the picture in the same folder where the .exe is. Running it from Visual Studios gives me an error, stating that the file is not found. Running the .exe manually however, works. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the "Working Directory" in your project settings -> Debugging.

Answer (score 1):

when run from the ide, your program started from another path, ie, the debug folder.

you can adjust the startup folder from the debugging settings in the project properties.